# JSON to Java class

Tags: java, android, json

Is there an easy way to map data from JSON to fields of my class by means of android APIs?

JSON:

```
{ email: 'email', password: 'pass' }
```

My class:

```
class Credentials
{
    string email;
    string password;
}
```

Comment: Here is an example: http://goo.gl/BsuaM

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/)-Package.

```
JSONObject x = new JSONObject(jsonString);
Credentials c = new Credentials();
c.email = x.getString("email");
c.password = x.getString("password");
```

Its also part of the android runtime, so you dont need any external package.

Comment: It is included indeed, but it does not exactly map data. It parses/writes JSON, and offers a simple node-based API. But it is Your code does doing mapping here.

Comment: I do it by making a constructor in the Credentials with the fields so I can do the same code in 2 lines instead.  JSONObject x = new JSONObject(jsonString);
Credentials c = new Credentials( x.getString("email"),x.getString("password"));

Comment: Use this => [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).
And this to create a POJO [JSONSCHEMA2POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org).

Answer (score 14):

Use [Jackson](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonInFiveMinutes). Much more convenient (and if performance matters, faster) than using bundled org.json classes and custom code:

```
Credentials c = new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, Credentials.class);
```

(just note that fields of Credentials need to be 'public' to be discovered; or need to have setter methods)

Answer (score 8):

You could use [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: be aware of this issue with HTC phones: http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-on-android

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have more than one Credential u want to get...

with the org.json package you could use a JSONArray to get various values at the same time out of one JSON file.