# How the Sugar Record model will be created for given JSON

Tags: android, sugarorm

I have following `JSON` and I want to create Sugar Record Class for it to store it in a `database` but I am not able to figure out weather I will need multiple model class or single would be enough please help me with this.

```
{
    "command": "AN",
    "tripId": 0,
    "tripData": {
        "DeviceId": "30050",
        "DispatcherId": 1,
        "PaxLimit": 50,
        "DriverId": 6,
        "Trips": [{
            "Stops": [{
                "Id": 1,
                "ScheduleTime": "06:00"
            }, {
                "Id": 5,
                "ScheduleTime": "07:00"
            }],
            "RouteId": 5,
            "ToStopId": 5,
            "TripId": 123,
            "FromStopId": 1
        }]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the **object** you want to store. Because [Sugar doesn't support 1 to many relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44879733/4585226). I see your `Trips` and `Stops` attributes (in the `JSON`) are both arrays in the `JSON`. It is not possible to save that in the Sugar database. Because you cannot store a `List` with Sugar.

You can choose for yourself if you would like one single class containing all attributes that are in the `JSON` object. The other options is to use `Nested Classes`.

It doesn't matter what option you choose because you can get the data out of the `JSON` [and put it in the right `Class`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4584574/4585226). The only thing that is important is that you can't use `Lists` in a `Class`.

So it really is your own choice if you use one or multiple classes.